# Randomly generate n unique numbers

Tags: c++, random, shuffle

If I want to generate 1000 numbers from 0 to 999, which are unique, what should I do?
My first attempt is to create a array {0, 1, 2, ..., 999} and use `std::random_shuffle` to shuffle them. However, since I have to generate the numbers in a long loop, let's say O(10^7), this approach will overwhelm the running time.
Is there any better way to solve this problem?

Comment: why would it take 10^7 to generate 100 numbers

Comment: @aaronman That's not what the OP said. He needs to generate them in a loop that will run about 10^7 times.

Comment: with a different set of random numbers each time? What is the purpose of this, I don't think we can solve the problem without more info, your not gonna generate a different set of random numbers each time without going through all 1000 numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you keep your array of 1000 numbers stored, and call `std::random_shuffle` each time you need to in your loop, that is actually the fastest way you'll be able to generate 1000 random unique numbers the way you need. You don't need to re-create the array each time.

It doesn't matter if your loop has O(10^7) iterations, because if you are going to use these 1000 integers as you say you need to, then it will already require O(n) operations just to traverse through each of these numbers as you use them. `std::random_shuffle` time complexity is also O(n) so it is not going to slow you down much more.

Comment: This. Generating 1000 numbers is O(n) and random_shuffle is O(n) also, so by definition you can't go any lower.

Comment: Asymptotically, yes. but simply reading values can be faster than generating them.

Comment: @Elazar Well, reading from a hard drive would actually be slower than shuffling them in memory. Also, it would require several GB of memory to store all the 10 billion numbers ;)

Comment: @Arthur Reading from the hard drive *synchronically* will probably be slower. yes.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for an implementation of `shuffle` (that's the accurate description of your requirement), which will be better than the one in the standard library. That's a long shot.

But I'll try. I would say: prepare a file with 10^7 such permutations, and read from it. Make sure to prefetch somehow, otherwise it will sure be slower. If you prefetch in different thread, it may actually be faster. But it's only a wild guess.

When I think about it, If you can run multithreaded you can use a simple producer-consumer solution. One thread putting permutations, the other simply reading them.

Answer (score 1):

1. Save your number container to another container C2.
2. Generate index of an element to pick random element in C1. Each time you generate an index, delete it from the container C1.
   So that, next time you will get unique number.
3. Once C1 becomes empty, repopulate C1 with C2 and go to step 2.